# IOS making buttons to work between viewcontrollers

Tags: ios

I asked a question similiar to this before and got many answers first of all thanks for them but because of the complexity of the project I didnt understand the answer so I decided to ask it again this time in a very simple form.

I have one button in viewcontrollerA and I want that button to write on a Label which is in viewcontrollerB.Its simple a button at A will set the Label text on B.

Example

User opens the app

Clicks the button at page A

Second Page comes up and in that page label text is set by the label.text code came from viewcontroller A it calls the code

Or maybe I can call the code of A from B its not important as long as I make it.I can make butons to open another viewcontrolers so you dont need to explain it.

Also if any other ways around and as long as they are simple I can do them too.Maybe I wrote the code elsewhere and call it from A and B.

Please explain it step by stem cause I have little knowlage about objective C and xcode.

I ask this question to learn about connections between viewcontrollers.In reality I will make that button to display a random number at the second page but its not important rightnow cause if I learn to make simple connection I can do the rest.

Comment: You say "Second Page comes up".  That's an important detail...how does that happen?  The answer you need is different depending on whether there's a segue involved or something done in code.

Answer (score 0):

In your action, you need to have a reference to the second view controller.  For example

```
- (IBAction)buttonAClicked:(id)sender {
    ViewController2 *vc2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
    vc2.someVariable = @"This is random text";
    [vc2.someButton setTitle:@"Some button text" forControlState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

This shows how you would create a second view controller, change two properties, and then push it.

Comment: I named my first view controlelr as Ru1 and second is Ru2 so I guess that I will put this ru1.h and write my viewcontroller names in this code.

But what is vc2 I guess you assigned a name its oke but is it distrupts my other connectios from the storyboard button click etc made for ru1 ru2

Comment: If you are trying to do this with storyboard.  You will want to name the segue and then do this in the - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender method

Comment: where should I write this code to the first viewcontroller.h or the second ?

Comment: You should be doing in firstcontroller.m, not .h

Comment: it gives an error and expects ; after sender and when I put it gives another errors ,

Comment: all right I corrected it but this time when I write my viewcontroller names instead of viewcontroller2 it cant find it but I declared them in storyboard make them custom class and named them.

Answer (score 0):

In your second view controller create a property called `theText` that is an `NSString` and then in the `viewDidLoad` assign the `label.text` to the `NSString`;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    if(self.theText)
        self.label.text = self.theText;
}
```

Now use your first view controller to set `theText` in the second view controller.

If you are using a segue use `prepareForSegue`:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Second View Segue"])
    {
        SecondViewController *theController = segue.destinationViewController;
        theController.theText = @"Some text";
    }
}
```

If you are using some sort of modal presentation:

```
SecondViewController *theController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
theController.theText = @"Some text";
[self presentModalViewController:theController animated:YES];
```

or if you are using a navigation controller:

```
SecondViewController *theController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
theController.theText = @"Some text";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:theController animated:YES];
```

So your first view controller will set the `NSString` property in the second, then the second will set the `UILabel` equal to the `NSString` during it's load.  You can not set the text of a `UILabel` before the second view controller is loaded, so something like:

```
SecondViewController *theController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
theController.label.text = @"Some text";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:theController animated:YES];
```

will not work correctly, because you can't set the text for the label until the view is loaded.

Hope that helps.